# How to add more than 1024 columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know is a design error, but is there a way to increment this capacity??

Comment: Its not always a design error. Sometimes, some hardwares generate csv files with thousands of columns. You may want to directly load them in db..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if its what you're looking for, but Sql Server has something called [wide tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx).

Comment: This may work but read the fine print. Most of the values in a wide table are expected to be null.

Comment: In this case, non value is null

Comment: so how do I define a wide table, include 'sparse' to table declaration...?

Comment: @Darkcminor:  Add a [column set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521.aspx).

Comment: It should be noted that even with SQL Server's sparse columns, which allow for 30K columns, each row is still limited to a little over 8K. So, if most columns have a value, it is likely it still wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a hard limit on 1024 columns per standard tables. One thing you can do is to add another table with a one-to-one relationship to the original table. In the second (or third or fourth) tables the pkey will also be the foreign key to the original.

Another thing you could do would be to use the [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) which would remove any upper bound on the number of fields per object but going with EAV is a change even more significant than adding more tables to handle extra fields.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design error.

Happy to help evaluate if you can describe the problem you're trying to solve that requires so many columns.

Comment: I've actually seen a need for this many columns in denormalization scenarios.

Comment: I'm not arguing there are no uses, just that it's unlikely.  Usually it's more helpful to step back to a proximate cause for a design than work around a tactical limitation like this.

Comment: I completely agree but we're both just speculating since we don't know why the OP needs so many columns.

Comment: I need to expand since I am storing lots of information like a tons of attributes (more than 2000) you know DNA and stuff...